# Get data from JSON from NSArray

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsarray, key-value

The data inside my NSArray is a JSON object which looks like this:

```
<modelObject 0x1714abe0> {
  key = 165825004;
  value = Hello I am the data
}
```

There are about 20 such objects in the array and I am trying to display the "value" from this object on a UITableView cell.

In "`(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`" I do:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

which crashes with an error:

```
[modelObject length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1714abe0"
```

I am assuming its throwing error because I have 2 key-value pairs or because its a JSON data. How do I handle this? I just want to display the data in "value" attribute on the cell i.e. in this case I want to display "Hello I am the data" on the cell.

Comment: You JSON object is a Dictionary not an array.

Comment: Its dictionary inside an array. Because I have multiple such objects inside myArray which is a NSMutable array. Its like myArray = [modelObject0, modelObject1, modelObject2,... , modelObject20]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should acesss value in this way

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"key"];
```

OR

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.myArray[indexPath.row][@"key"];
```

Comment: Easier to use `cell.textLabel.text = self.myArray[indexPath.row][@"value"];`

Comment: Thanks that works... Just one correction... Its valueForKey which worked for me and not objectForKey. :)

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath put this line of code...
employeeName data taken from dictionary into which JSON data is put

`cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]employeeName]];`